# Wordpress: перенос одного из мультисайтов на новый домен

Tags: wordpress

Имеем мультисайт *domain.com* на Wordpress с кучей поддоменов *wp_1*, *wp_2* и т.п.

Есть новый домен *newdomain.com* на который в качестве основного сайта надо перенести один из поддоменов: *wp_2*.

Как это сделать максимально быстро, не переименовывая кучу таблиц?

Answer (score 0):

Пока самым простым решением нашёл ручное удаление таблиц *wp_blogs*, *wp_options* и т.п. с переименованием *wp_2_blogs*, *wp_2_options* и т.п. в *wp_blogs*, *wp_options* и т.п.

Ну, и соответственно `UPDATE` в таблицах любых упоминаний прошлого домена